# Customizing MUI 6 Datecalendar to Support Ethiopian Calendar System with 13 Months

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui-x-date-picker

I'm working on a project where I need to use the MUI 6 Datecalendar component, but I want to customize it to support the Ethiopian calendar system, which has 13 months.

How can I properly configure the Datecalendar component to recognize the Ethiopian 13-month system?
Is there a specific way to extend or override the default dateAdapter functionality to support this requirement?
Are there any known libraries or tools that might ease this integration with the Ethiopian calendar?
Any guidance or references would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried to create a custom dateAdapter using date-fns, but it doesn't recognize the 13th month.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.